# In a Typoscript HMENU, how to force the language for the URL

Tags: typo3, typoscript, realurl, typo3-4.5

I have a multi-language, multi-site, multi-domain TYPO3 (4.5) Instance where RealURL keeps me busy. In some sub-sites, I just can't get it to create the right URLs for Languages 1 and 2.

It will result in the pattern www.language-2-domain.com/language-1-pagetitle

Instead of keeping on fiddling with realurl_conf, I would like to know if/how it is possible to tell a TMENU to force use a certain language - then I could solve it with a condition.

Here's a completely normal TMENU:

```
lib.content_sitemap = COA
lib.content_sitemap {
5 = HMENU
5 {
  wrap = <ul>|</ul>
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    expAll = 1
    noBlur = 1
    NO {
       wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
       text = nav_title // title
     }

   ACT < .NO
   ACT {
       wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
       }
   ACT = 1

   CUR < .NO
   CUR {
       wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
       }
   CUR = 1
    }
  }
}
```

Now what I could use would be something like

```
5.1.NO.text.sys_language_uid = 1
```

Is there something like that?

EDIT: I see, it's not the "text" that's concerned. Can I build the typolink in NO by hand with "doNotLinkIt" and force the language there?

Comment: So this would be the same technical use case as "output HMENU from another language version on the current page"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an obvious example of "get desperate and look for hacks instead of looking at the problem after a good night's sleep".

There were inconsistencies in the RealURL Config which provoked the erroneous behaviour.

I'm posting the hopefully fully working RealURL config.
It covers two single-domain/multi-language websites as well as two multi-domain/multi-language websites. That is why I use the [regex](http://blog.teamgeist-medien.de/2013/09/hardcore-realurl-mehrere-domains-prevars-sprachen-rootpages-decodeencode.html) on the URL.

```
 <?php
 $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array (
    '_DEFAULT' => array (
        'init' => array(
            'enableCHashCache' => 1,
            'respectSimulateStaticURLs' => 0,
            'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile',
            'enableUrlDecodeCache' => 1,
            'enableUrlEncodeCache' => 1,
        ),
        'preVars' => array(
            array(
                 'GETvar' => 'L',
                 'valueMap' => array(
                                    'de' => '0',
                                    'fr' => '1',
                                    'it' => '2',
                            ),
                 'valueDefault' => 'de',
                 'noMatch' => 'bypass',
            ),
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'no_cache',
                'valueMap' => array(
                    'no_cache' => 1,
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
            ),
        ),
        'pagePath' => array (
            'rootpage_id' => 1,
            'type' => 'user',
            'disablePathCache' => 0,
            'userFunc' =>
            'EXT:realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php:&tx_realurl_advanced->main',
            'spaceCharacter' => '-',
            'languageGetVar' => 'L',
            'expireDays' => 3
        ),
        'fileName' => array(
            'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => 0,
        ),
    ),
);

/* site1 and site2 are single-domain */

/* site3 */
# http://blog.teamgeist-medien.de/2013/09/hardcore-realurl-mehrere-domains-prevars-sprachen-rootpages-decodeencode.html

if (    preg_match('/(www\.)?site3-d\.ch/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) > 0 
    ||  preg_match('/(www\.)?site3-f\.ch/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) > 0 
    ||  preg_match('/(www\.)?site3-i\.ch/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) > 0 ) {

$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['site3'] = $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'];
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['site3']['pagePath']['rootpage_id'] = '618';

$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DOMAINS'] = array(
    'encode' => array(
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'value' => '',
            'useConfiguration' => 'site3',
            'urlPrepend' => 'http://www.site3-d.ch',
        ),
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'value' => '0',
            'useConfiguration' => 'site3',
            'urlPrepend' => 'http://www.site3-d.ch',
        ),
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'value' => '1',
            'useConfiguration' => 'site3',
            'urlPrepend' => 'http://www.site3-f.ch'
        ),
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'value' => '2',
            'useConfiguration' => 'site3',
            'urlPrepend' => 'http://www.site3-i.ch',
        ),
    ),
    'decode' => array(
        'www.site3-d.ch' => array(
            'GETvars' => array(
                'L' => '0',
            ),
            'useConfiguration' => 'site3',
        ),
        'www.site3-f.ch' => array(
            'GETvars' => array(
                'L' => '1',
            ),
            'useConfiguration' => 'site3',
        ),
        'www.site3-i.ch' => array(
            'GETvars' => array(
                'L' => '2',
            ),
            'useConfiguration' => 'site3',
        ),
    ),
);
}

/**      site4    */

if (    preg_match('/(www\.)?site4-d\.ch/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) > 0 
    ||  preg_match('/(www\.)?site4-f\.ch/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) > 0 ) {

// default Konfiguration übernehmen
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['site4'] = $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'];
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['site4']['pagePath']['rootpage_id'] = '574';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['site4']['preVars'] = array();

$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DOMAINS'] = array(
    'encode' => array(
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'value' => '',
            'useConfiguration' => 'site4',
            'urlPrepend' => 'http://www.site4-d.ch',
        ),
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'value' => '0',
            'useConfiguration' => 'site4',
            'urlPrepend' => 'http://www.site4-d.ch',
        ),
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'value' => '1',
            'useConfiguration' => 'site4',
            'urlPrepend' => 'http://www.site4-f.ch'
        ),
    ),
    'decode' => array(
        'www.site4-d.ch' => array(
            'GETvars' => array(
                'L' => '0',
            ),
            'useConfiguration' => 'site4',
        ),
        'www.site4-f.ch' => array(
            'GETvars' => array(
                'L' => '1',
            ),
            'useConfiguration' => 'site4',
        ),
    ),
);
}


?>
```