# How to 301 redirect a part of a URL with htaccess ( /en/ to / )

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, typo3

I want to 301 redirect all references /en/ in a website, currently there are multple websites running on the same TYPO3 installation. For example all references would keep the same structure.

For example *my-domain.com/en/* would simply go to *my-domain.com*, and *my-domain.com/en/about-us* would go to *my-domain.com/about-us*

Because there are multiple websites and domains running I would need to define the domain using RewriteCond. I have tried the following snippet, but no joy.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

What would be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Is `/en/` a real directory?

Comment: No /en/ never even existed, but I get alot of 404 errors for something looking for the all pages with /en/ added. I want to redirect these calls to the normal pages on the website.

Comment: Then your rule should work if this rule is first rule in your .htaccess

Comment: Doesn't you want to offer English version anymore ? remember that /en/ part should is added with RealURL probably as a substitution of the `?L=x` param

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

In addition to that configure your realurl prevars like this, to target your specific domain:

```
 $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['www.domain.com'] = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'];

 $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['www.domain.com']['preVars'] => array (
            '0' => array (
                'GETvar' => 'L',
                'valueMap' => array (
                    //'en' => '0', // remove the language here
                    'de' => '2', // any other language...

                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass' // thats the important bit
            ),
        ),
```

The important part on the realurl config is to keep out the default language from being integratet in the url via noMatch => bypass and removing it from the value array.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. Though I think the problem with this setup, is that there are other websites running on the same TYPO3 installation that actually do have an /en/ version. Editing the realurl will disable it for all running websites, right? Unless there is a way to add an exception in realurl just like you can in .htaccess ...

Comment: I've updated the answer to target a specific domain within your installation. This copies the `_DEFAULT` and overrides the `preVars` only.

Comment: @konsolenfreddy btw - what do you think about the solution on http://stackoverflow.com/a/28472627/160968 for complex multi-site / multi-domain-site installations (combining _DOMAINS with a preg_match on the hostname)?